# Json.dump not showing values just keys

Tags: python, json

I am running through a dir of files, grabbing the json from each file and I want to merge into one file.

```
for filename in os.listdir(r):
    f = os.path.join(r,filename)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        
        with open(f, 'r') as f:
         data += json.load(f)
        print(data)
        with open(metadataFilePath, 'w') as m:
            json.dump(data, m, indent=4)
```

I am not getting values with the keys and I don't seem to be getting a pretty print either. This is the result.

```
 {},
    "name",
    "description",
    "image",
    "compiler",
    "creator",
    "attributes",
    "name",
    "description",
    "image",
    "compiler",
    "creator",
    "attributes",
    "name",
    "description",
    "image",
    "compiler",
    "creator",
    "attributes",
```

I'd like to have:

```
{
  "name": "Frame #10000",
  "description": "Frames",
  "image": "10000.jpg",
  "compiler": "Frames compiler",
  "creator": "aaronde",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Frame in Film",
      "value": "122759"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Onscreen",
      "value": "End Credits"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Frame #10000",
  "description": "Frames",
  "image": "10000.jpg",
  "compiler": "Frames compiler",
  "creator": "aaronde",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Frame in Film",
      "value": "122759"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Onscreen",
      "value": "End Credits"
    }
  ]
}
```

Defining data as [] seems to remove the values and the print shows all the data in the consoled.

Comment: What is the initial value of `data`?

Comment: I think you want `data.append(json.load(f))`

Comment: `data += json.load(f)` is like `data.extend(json.load(f))`.

Comment: Maybe `data = json.load(f)`?

Comment: @Barmar data.append(json.load(f)) did the trick. I tried before in a different manner and was getting dict errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per @barmar the solution was to use: data.append(json.load(f))
final code was:

```
pattern = "*.json"
metadataFilePath = "..\_metadata.json"
files = sorted(os.listdir(r), key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0]))  

data = []        

for filename in files:
    if fnmatch(filename, pattern):
        f = os.path.join(r,filename)
    
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            with open(f, 'r') as f:
             data.append(json.load(f))


with open(metadataFilePath, 'w') as m:
    json.dump(data, m, indent=4)
```

Comment: BTW, instead of using `os.listdir()` followed by `fnmatch()`, use `glob.glob()`.